# Evaluating $\sum_{r=1}^{2001} f\left(\frac{r}{2002}\right)$, where $f(x)=\frac{4^{x}}{4^{x}+2}$

Tags: functions, summation-method

> Let
>   $
> f(x)=\dfrac{4^{x}}{4^{x}+2}
> $. Find
>   $
> \sum_{r=1}^{2001} f\left(\frac{r}{2002}\right)
> $.

Given,

$$f(x)=\frac{4^{x}}{4^{x}+2}$$

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{r=1}^{2001} f\left(\frac{r}{2002}\right) &=\sum_{r=1}^{2001} \frac{4^{\frac{r}{2002}}}{4^{\frac{r}{2002}}+2} \\[4pt]
&=\frac{4^{\sum_{r=1}^{2001}\frac{r}{2002}}}{4^{\sum_{r=1}^{2001}\frac{r}{2002}}+2}  \\[4pt]
&=\frac{4^{\frac{1}{2002}+\frac{2}{2002}+\cdots \cdot \frac{2001}{2002}}}{4^{\frac{1}{2002}+\frac{2}{2002}+\cdots \cdot \frac{2001}{2002}} +2}
\end{align}$$

Upon simplifying, I am getting

$$\frac{4^{{2001}}}{4^{{2001}}+2}$$

> What to do next?

Comment: I suggest working the sum for smaller numbers (smaller than $2002, 2001$ that is).  A pattern will quickly emerge.

Comment: @lulu am I going correct direction? Or i am wrong in my steps?

Comment: I can't follow your calculation.  In any case, the final answer appears to be a lot simpler than that.

Comment: @lulu will u please elaborate! .I am getting no clue.

Comment: I gave you a suggestion.  Work the same problem for smaller numbers.  The answer will become clear very quickly (though it may still take some work to prove that it is correct).

Comment: $$\sum_{r=1}^{2001} f\left(\frac{r}{2002}\right) =\sum_{r=1}^{2001} \frac{4^{\frac{r}{2002}}}{4^{\frac{r}{2002}}+2} \\
=\frac{4^{\sum_{r=1}^{2001}\frac{r}{2002}}}{4^{\sum_{r=1}^{2001}\frac{r}{2002}}+2}$$ How did you get this step? How can you transfer the sum to the power?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг i have done the same thing.Tell me next process

Comment: @RANCHO: Moving the summation to the exponents is unjustified. You can't write, say, $$\frac{4^a}{4^a+2}+\frac{4^b}{4^b+2}=\frac{4^{a+b}}{4^{a+b}+2}$$

Comment: No, that step is wrong, simple. You need to think of a different way of simplification. lulu is telling you that you should try to compute $\sum_{r=1}^3 f(\frac r{4})$ and so on, to get a hint of something : a telescoping sum?Lots of cancellations? Combining two terms of the summation produces a simplification?

Comment: @Blue,ok I am unaware  of that!

Comment: Hint: $f(x) + f(1-x) = ?$

Comment: @achille hui  I am not getting u sorry

Comment: @RANCHO pick a caculator, pick a random $x \in [0,1]$ compute the expression $f(x) + f(1-x)$. pick another $x$ and repeat the calculation, you get the same number....

Comment: @Rancho This is because the function has been chosen to behave like this. There are not too many tricks to create sums/integrals that looks very complicated but has a way to evaluate it easily. A common trick is make the terms of opposite end of the sum/integral always average to same number. Ever heard of Gauss's story of computing the sum from 1 to 100 when he is a kid?

Comment: @achille hui yeah! for the Sum of the first 100 whole numbers,Gauss realized  that the final total would be 50(101) = 5050........

Answer (score 0):

There is a different way to solve this question.
You need use this identity $\mathit f(x) + f(1-x) = 1$.

Let me prove this first $\pmb :$

$\mathit f(x) = \frac{4^x}{(4^x+2)}----->1 $

Replace $\mathit x\;$ as $\mathit 1-x\\$

$\mathit f(x) = \frac{4^{1-x}}{4^{1-x}+2} = \frac{4\cdot{4^{-x}}}{4\cdot{4^{-x}}+2}$

On simplifying you get $\mathit f(x) = \frac{4}{4+2\cdot{4^x}}$ $\;$ which simplifies as $\mathit = \;\frac{2}{2+{4^x}}----->2$

Add $\mathit equation \;\pmb1$ and $\pmb2\;$ you get the number $\pmb 1$ as the answer.

Now applying this in the summation $$\sum_{i=0}^{2001} \mathit f\left(\frac{r}{2002}\right) $$

Substituting values from $\pmb1$ to $\pmb{2001}$

$\mathit f\left(\frac{1}{2002}\right)$ + $\mathit f\left(\frac{2}{2002}\right)$ + ....... +  $\mathit f\left(\frac{1001}{2002}\right)$ + ....... $\mathit f\left(\frac{2000}{2002}\right)$ + $\mathit f\left(\frac{2001}{2002}\right)$

Group the terms $\pmb :$ $\mathit f\left(\frac{1}{2002}\right)$ + $\mathit f\left(\frac{2001}{2002}\right)$ + $\mathit f\left(\frac{2}{2002}\right)$ + $\mathit f\left(\frac{2000}{2002}\right)$ + ........ + $\mathit f\left(\frac{1000}{2002}\right)$ + $\mathit f\left(\frac{1002}{2002}\right)$ + $\mathit f\left(\frac{1001}{2002}\right)$

Now we have grouped $\pmb {2000}$ terms whose sum is $\pmb {1,}$ added $\pmb {2000}$ times.

Finally we have to add the middle term $\mathit f\left(\frac{1001}{2002}\right)$ whose value we can find by substituting $\pmb {\frac{1}{2}}$ in the question $\mathit f(x) = \frac{4^x}{(4^x+2)}$. It's value is $\pmb {\frac{1}{2}}$.

So the final answer is $\mathit 1000 + \frac{1}{2}$ which is $\pmb {\frac{2001}{2}}$

Cheers!!